# Sketching curves with derivatives.

Tags: calculus

The curve $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ contains the point $(0,5)$ and has a stationary point at $(2,-14)$. Calculate the values of $a, b$ and $c$. 
I know that stationary points have a gradient of $0$ but I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Please show your attempts!

Answer (score 2):

$(0,5)$ is on the curve, the  it must satisfy the equation(i.e. $y(0)=5$), substitute in the equation and you'll get $c=5$

Now $(2,-14)$ is a stationary point, which means here that the derivative $y'=2ax+b$ is $0$ when $x=2$ (i.e. $y'(2)=0$), so $0=4a+b$,

We still need a third equation to get the **3 unknowns**, we get this third equation from the fact that the point $(2,-14)$ is also on the curve (i.e. $y(2)=-14$), so by substituting we get $-14=4a+2b+5$

Now it is a system of 2 equations in 2 unknowns, can you complete it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle y(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$

$\displaystyle y(0) = c = 5$ (Given)

$\displaystyle y'(x) = 2ax + b = 0$ at $x = 2$

or, $\displaystyle 4a + b = 0$

Also

$\displaystyle y(2) = 4a + 2b + c = -14$

Solving,

$\displaystyle a = \frac{19}{4}$

$\displaystyle b = -19$

Hence $\displaystyle y(x) = \frac{19}{4} x^2 - 19x + 5$

Please check the calculations.

Comment: Please don't give full answers to questions with no context?